# Meteor publish don't work with findOne

Tags: meteor

I was trying to use findOne in publish method but seems like i'm getting error if i don't use collection. So was that an issue with publish method?

Error:

```
I20151205-10:59:28.478(-5)? Exception from sub userConnections id YdJbkeazXZqZayFLd Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors
I20151205-10:59:28.479(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend._publishHandlerResult (livedata_server.js:1107:18)
I20151205-10:59:28.479(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (livedata_server.js:1038:10)
I20151205-10:59:28.479(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (livedata_server.js:842:9)
I20151205-10:59:28.480(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (livedata_server.js:614:12)
I20151205-10:59:28.480(-5)?     at _.extend.processMessage.processNext (livedata_server.js:548:43)
```

Publish method

```
Meteor.publish('userConnections', function(){
    if(!this.userId){
       return;
    }
    return Connections.findOne({userId: this.userId});
})
```

Subscript Method

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe('userConnections').then(function(){
     $scope.userContacts = $scope.$meteorObject(Connections);
    }, false);
```

### Update

I don't see any explanation  in previous [stackflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515309/meteor-publish-undefined-or-publish-function-can-only-return-a-cursor-or-an-arra) about what we can use with publish method. Can you anyone explain?

Comment: Which part is not clear? As both the answer and @MatthiasEckhart 's answer state you should call `find()` instead of `findOne()`, as `findOne()` does not return a cursor.

Comment: Can i not use anything other than returning a cursor?

Comment: @user1595858 No, you need to return a cursor or an array of cursors.

Comment: @user1595858 you can do `doc = Collection.findOne(); this.added('collectionName', doc._id, doc); this.ready()` as documented here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish (second example). It's a slightly different approach where you have more control but have to keep things up to date yourself.